# My app keeps crashing when i try to run it (New to this)

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
private double mmiles,mgallons = 1;
EditText miles;
EditText gallons;
Button execute;
TextView fin;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);







    execute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            miles = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMiles);
            gallons = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextGallons);
            mmiles = Double.parseDouble(miles.getText().toString());
            execute= (Button) findViewById(R.id.execute);
            fin= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fini);
            String numberAsString = new Double(mmiles).toString();
            fin.setText(numberAsString);
        }
    });
}}
```

Every time i start the app it crashes. Im trying to store a number from a EditText into a TextView to start with. I am new to java programming so im having a hard time figuring this out.

EDIT: Still doesnt seem to display anything. Here's what I have so far:

```
      execute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            miles = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMiles);
            gallons = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextGallons);
            mmiles = Double.parseDouble(miles.getText().toString());
            String TextAsString = String.valueOf(mmiles);
            fin= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fini);

            fin.setText(TextAsString);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Please check for the error in android monitor and paste the log

Comment: Because `execute` is `null`. move `execute= (Button) findViewById(R.id.execute);` line after `setContentView`

Answer (score 0):

Use a different name for the button, I don't think "execute" is a reserved keyword but it can mean other things later (with AsyncTask) on so it's confusing at first

You need this line right before your `execute.setOnClickListener...` line:

```
execute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.execute);
```

The reason being is that up until that point all you told the compiler is that execute *is* a button but it doesn't know *what* button to which you're referring.

Also, change `String numberAsString = new Double(mmiles).toString();` to `String numberAsString = String.valueOf(mmiles);`

Comment: Thanks! that stopped the crashing, but now when i click the execute button it sets the TextView to no text at all

Comment: Still doesnt display anything. Here's what i have (see edit)

Comment: I think in your parseDouble method you want to getText() from mmiles, not miles ..